# Should closed Mint questions be reopened if the OP edits to say Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, a Mint user will ask a question here. It will then be closed as per the site policy. *Then*, the OP will notice Mint questions wont be answered and edit it to *say* he's using Ubuntu. It's possible that they're still using Mint, but saying Ubuntu (OTIOH, it's still possible that they've switched).

In cases like these, should the question be reopened?

I'm inclined to trust the OP, however would like a community opinion on this.

Answer (score 3):

If it is just a one for one switch from mint to Ubuntu edit, I would say no. (especially there were previous comments like "why not"  and "it is *based* on..."

---

If there is a clear sentence saying "I have since switch to Ubuntu, and have the same problem with ..." I think we should believe and reopen.